# Calling forms in j2me

Tags: java, java-me

Hi i want to call a form from my main form in my j2me app. Normally in java we give a call to the constructor. But in here i am not able to do that. I need some help please.

Answer (score 2):

First u need to create a instance of that form and with the help of this instance you can call a other form from the form .. .